# PhoneGap architecture design

Tags: cordova, mobile, architecture

I'm going to write my first phonegap app (for tablets) and i'm not sure in what way I should organize its structure:

1. one .html file with many divs, that I change with js.
2. many .html files

What is the best practice in PhoneGap development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Both method is good but i would suggest 2nd option because its easy to manage separate files rather then one file.

You can get your html files contain using

```
$.get(file_name, function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

jquery function and you can innerHtml to any DIV or Document Body